# Why can't I merge unallocated space to my linux partition?

Tags: gparted

[image]

Why can't I merge the unallocated space to sda4? (sda4 linux, sda2 windows partition)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Because partitions can be resized only to the right, resizing them to the left requires copying the existing data which GParted cannot do when the partition is in use (mounted), you'll need to do the resize/move operation from a LiveCD.

Comment: So, could I do it logged in on windows instead? (sda2)

Comment: I don't know if there is a tool that can do that from Windows. You can use the Ubuntu Live CD, it has GParted.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you have booted from this file system.

Online resize can only add space at the end, everything else needs to be done while the file system is unmounted, which it can't be because it's in use.

You can boot from a "rescue" system like [GRML](https://grml.org/) and repartition from there.